# Vuetify ignoring v-cloak

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am unable to prevent the initial flash of content problem when using Vuetify. I have previously achieved this with the usual `v-cloak` solution when using Vue without any UI libraries but for whatever reason this is not working with Vuetify and I am still getting the flash of unstyled content before the JS has finished loading.

I have the initial `index.html` with this in it (even tried inline `display: none`):

```
<head>
    <style>
        [v-cloak] {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app" v-cloak style="display: none;"></div>
    ...
</body>
```

And then in the initial `app.vue` file:

```
<template>
    <div id="app" v-cloak>
        <v-app v-cloak>
        ...
<style>
    [v-cloak] {
        display: none;
    }
```

For some reason both the inline `display: none` and the multiple `v-cloak`'s are being overridden I assume by Vuetify. How should I work around this bug so that the user doesn't get the initial flash while loading?

Comment: The inline thing is very weird because Vue/Vuetify could only overwrite it once the App is actually controlling the DOM and has rendered - at which point there could be no FOUG anymore because, well, the app has already rendered.

Comment: Try to apply v-cloak="true" instead of just v-cloak

Comment: Nope setting it to true doesn't fix it. Guess I just have to hope the user won't mind the flash.

Answer (score 3):

This is a little late, but the issue seems to be that the page starts rendering before all the styles have been applied. To solve this, you can simply `mount` your view instance `onload`:

```
import App from './components/App.vue'

const vm = new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
})

window.onload = function() {
  vm.$mount('#app');
}
```